# Extract Images from OneNote Page, Section, or File

Tags: onenote

Is there a way, either through native features or through code, that I can extract all the images from a OneNote page (for example created by OfficeLens or just embedding the image in the Page) and save them as JPGs (or another format)? Ideally I'd like to get them into SharePoint Online.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the page recall APIs to get all the images from a page. They are in BETA right now.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/onenotedev/archive/2014/09/18/new-beta-api-page-recall.aspx

Comment: Thanks! I have seen many API examples, what I am not clear on is "Where does the code run?" The samples indicate using REST so does this mean I have to create an external application? Are the days of creating a button in the Ribbon to handle this kind of thing gone? It really won't work for my users if the action to remove the images is not in the context of the page they are looking at.

Comment: The new OneNote API is cloud based (REST) so that it will work on any platform and intended for 3rd party developers to include in their apps. If you're looking for a feature in the clients, please give us feedback at onenote.uservoice.com

Comment: So in this case how would you approach this as a solution? Do you have a high level idea because I don't see how it would be implemented in OneNote.